# Alignment of entries in matrix

Tags: horizontal-alignment, matrices

I have this `pmatrix` (`amsmath` package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{a}{b}     & \frac{a}{b}     & 0  & 1-\frac{a}{b} \\ 
0               & 0               & -1 & 0             \\ 
c-\frac{a}{b}   & c-\frac{a}{b}   & 0  & \frac{a}{b}   \\ 
d+c-\frac{a}{b} & d+c-\frac{a}{b} & 0  & -\frac{a}{b}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to align entries of the matrix so all fractions are aligned. Is there a way to to this within the `pmatrix` environment, or do I have to use `\begin{array}`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: this limitation of the compact matrices is stated in the `amsmath` manual (`texdoc amsmath`, p.8, sec.4.1): "If you need left or right alignment in a column or other special formats you must resort to array."

Answer (score 12):

The `mathtools` package allows to adjust the alignment of matrix elements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
\frac{a}{b}     & \frac{a}{b}     & 0  & 1-\frac{a}{b} \\
0               & 0               & -1 & 0             \\
c-\frac{a}{b}   & c-\frac{a}{b}   & 0  & \frac{a}{b}   \\
d+c-\frac{a}{b} & d+c-\frac{a}{b} & 0  & -\frac{a}{b}
\end{pmatrix*}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is actually the simplest answer of all, no new command, and no extra environment. Very good point, using package options is usually a plus.

Comment: `pmatrix` seems only to support a single alignment for all columns

Comment: If you need to change the alignment for a single entry, use `\hfill` to push the entry to one side or the other. If you place `\hfill` on both sides, then the entry will be centered.

Answer (score 6):

This uses `array` environment

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{rrrr}
\frac{a}{b}     & \frac{a}{b}     & 0  & 1-\frac{a}{b} \\ 
0               & 0               & -1 & 0             \\ 
c-\frac{a}{b}   & c-\frac{a}{b}   & 0  & \frac{a}{b}   \\ 
d+c-\frac{a}{b} & d+c-\frac{a}{b} & 0  &-\frac{a}{b}
\end{array}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use a `\makebox` to ensure that each column was set in the same size box and set the alignment to be `r`ight aligned:

[image]

### Notes:

- Using a simple `hphantom{}` to insert sufficient space to right align all the entries mostly works, except that it is difficult to get the very last entry correct and still have the unary negative spacing as opposed to a binary minus spacing.
- I left the constants with centered spacing -- this could be adjusted as well if desired.

---

The second problem (mentioned in the comments) about centering the `0` within the parenthesis requires a bit more crafting in terms of where `\phantom` spaces are introduced and how large the `\makebox` is made:

[image]

Hopefully you can study the code below and be able to achieve any alignments you desire.  I don't believe that there is a generic solution that works in all cases, each case needs to be conditioned on a case by case basis.

### Notes:

- I added some vertical spacing of below the first row via `\\[0.5ex]`.

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand*{\MakeBox}[2]{\makebox[\widthof{#1}][r]{#2}}%

\newcommand{\ColumnA}[1]{\MakeBox{$d + c - \frac{1}{b}$}{$#1$}}%
\newcommand{\ColumnD}[1]{\MakeBox{$1 - \frac{1}{b}$}{$#1$}}%

\newcommand{\PhantomFrac}{\hphantom{\frac{1}{2}}}%
\newcommand{\PhantomRe}{\hphantom{\Re\text{e}}}%
\newcommand{\PhantomIm}{\hphantom{\Im\text{m}}}%
\newcommand{\CenterInAPlusB}[1]{\PhantomFrac\makebox[\widthof{$(a+b)$}][c]{$#1$}}%
\newcommand{\CenterInATimesB}[2]{#1\makebox[\widthof{$(ab)$}][c]{$#2$}}%


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}{}
\ColumnA{\frac{a}{b}}    & \ColumnA{\frac{a}{b}}     & 0  & 1-\frac{a}{b} \\ 
0                        & 0                         & -1 & 0             \\ 
\ColumnA{c  -\frac{a}{b}}& \ColumnA{c  -\frac{a}{b}} & 0  & \ColumnD{\frac{a}{b}}  \\ 
         d+c-\frac{a}{b} & d+c-\frac{a}{b}           & 0  & \ColumnD{-\frac{a}{b}}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{1}{2}(a+b)   & \frac{1}{2}(a-b)   & \CenterInATimesB{\PhantomRe}{0} & \CenterInATimesB{\PhantomIm}{0} \\[0.5ex] 
\frac{1}{2}(a-b)   & \frac{1}{2}(a+b)   & \CenterInATimesB{\PhantomRe}{0} & \CenterInATimesB{\PhantomIm}{0} & 0 & \Im\text{m}(a b) & \Re\text{e}(a b)\\ 
\CenterInAPlusB{0} & \CenterInAPlusB{0} & \Re\text{e}(a b)                & \Im\text{m}(a b) 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That works great, and solves the problem I posted. I have a second matrix where it doesn't. I'd like to have all the zeros aligned with the center of the brackets:
`code`    \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2}(a+b) & \frac{1}{2}(a-b) &              0    &              0 \\
    \frac{1}{2}(a-b) & \frac{1}{2}(a+b) &              0    &              0 
                 0   &              0   & \Im\text{m}(a b)  & \Re\text{e}(a b)\\
                 0   &              0   & \Re\text{e}(a b)  & \Im\text{m}(a b)
    \end{array}
    \end{pmatrix}

Comment: @ Peter: I am sure this works too. Unfortunately my real problem is not that simple. All the a's and b's in the fractions get different indices and are therefore different.

Comment: @Philipp: Have updated solution to show how to do the problem you mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution to the first problem is using the matrix* environments defined in the `mathtools`package  For the second problem, I simplify a little the code defining in a simpler way `\RE` and `\IM` as math operators : the vertical spacing problem is taken care of using the `cellspace` package : it ensures a minimal spacing between the bottom of a line and the top of the next line in  array-type environments ; works with the amsmath environments – but unfortunately not with the mathtools extensions.

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\IM}{\Im{m}}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\RE}{\Re{e}}
    \usepackage[math]{cellspace}
    \cellspacetoplimit = 3pt
    \cellspacebottomlimit = 3pt

    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix*}[r]
    \dfrac{a}{b}     & \dfrac{a}{b}     & 0  & 1-\dfrac{a}{b} \\[8pt]
    0               & 0               & -1 & 0             \\[4pt]
    c-\dfrac{a}{b}   & c-\dfrac{a}{b}   & 0  & \dfrac{a}{b}   \\[12pt]
    d+c-\dfrac{a}{b} & d+c-\dfrac{a}{b} & 0  & -\dfrac{a}{b}
    \end{pmatrix*}
    \end{equation}
    \bigskip
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2}(a+b) & \frac{1}{2}(a-b) & 0 & 0 \\
    \frac{1}{2}(a-b) & \frac{1}{2}(a+b) & 0 & 0 & 0 & \IM(a b) & \RE(a b)\\
     0 & 0 & \RE(a b) & \IM(a b)
     \end{pmatrix}
    \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

[image]